# Download a txt file from EDGAR

Tags: python, download, edgar

I want to download this file to my local drive:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1556179/0001104659-20-000861.txt

Here are my codes:

```
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
  
path=r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1556179/0001104659-20-000861.txt" 
r=requests.get(path, headers={"User-Agent": "b2g"})
content=r.content.decode('utf8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")
soup=str(soup)
lines=soup.split("\\n")

dest_url=r"C://Users/YL/Downloads/a.txt"
fx=open(dest_url,'w')
for line in lines:
    fx.write(line + '\n')
```

Here is the error message:
[image]

How should I download the file then? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: The EDGAR data famously contains Unicode errors; that's the root cause of your problem.

Comment: I _know_ there is a duplicate but I can't find it. Basically, the EDGAR people seem to have invented their own bastard version of UTF-8  (or was it Windows-1252?) which isn't compatible with any real encoding; you have to find the offending bytes and replace them with the correct ones. It's a mechanical change once you see what's wrong. Search for Python questions about encoding errors with an answer by MartijnPieters (I think it was?) and comments by myself, or perhaps vice versa.

Comment: The URL in your example seems to contain completely correct character codes, though. The immediate problem seems to be that `soup = str(soup)` is not a good idea. Did you mean `soup = soup.text`  perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download is fine. The problem is that `str(soup)` is not well-defined, and throws `html5lib` into an endless loop. You probably meant

```
soup = soup.text
```

which (crudely) extracts the actual readable text from the BeatifulSoup object.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has downloaded alright; it seems there's a problem with BeautifulSoup's parsing. Try changing the parser and doing it this way:

```
path=r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1556179/0001104659-20-000861.txt" 
r=requests.get(path, headers={"User-Agent": "b2g"})
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
soup
```

and you'll see the file is there.

Comment: I replaced my codes with the three lines you have written, but the error message is "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable". Could you please help me to fix the problem? Thank you!

Comment: @Julie Not sure why you're getting that error. I edited the answer using the full code (which worked for me). Try it now and see if it works.